# SUMPRODUCT several ifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I´ve spent a lot of time with a formula in Excel and I´m still blocked. I hope you can help me.

I have a table in Excel with several values as shown in this
[screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTS5b.png)

What I´m trying to extract is the number of Fruits sold in a specific month. That is, how many lemons were sold in January 2016, for example. This is the formula I´m using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:B38=E4)*(MONTH($A$3:$A$150)=12)*(YEAR($A$3:$A$150)=2015);$C$3:$C$150)
```

But the result is #N/A as seen in the screenshot.

What Am I doing wrong? Any help, please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. I have no idea what a pivot table is...:S...I will have a look though...

Comment: Interestingly, this tutorial uses fruits and vegetables for its example: http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html . In general, a great deal of somewhat complicated lookup/ calculation is already built into pivot tables. There is a bit of a learning curve, but the only way to be an Excel power user is to master them.

Comment: That is exactly the site I'm having a look at the moment. The problem I´m having now is the way of showing the results as I was expecting by month and year and not by the exact date. Still working on it. Thanks a lot John.

Comment: By the way, I prefer to keep using the SUMPRODUCT formula, so, if somebody can help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is your ranges are not equal in length. B3:B38 has to be the same number of rows as $A$3:$A$150 and C3:C150.  When rows are not equal things blow up on you.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$150=$E4)*(MONTH($A$3:$A$150)=12)*(YEAR($A$3:$A$150)=2015);$C$3:$C$150)
```

if you change your header row to be actual excel date format, and then change the cell display format to just show the month (as suggested by csanjose), then you can adjust your sumproduct formula as follows and copy to all cells in your table.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$38=$E4)*(MONTH($A$3:$A$150)=Month(F$3))*(YEAR($A$3:$A$150)=Year(F$3));$C$3:$C$150)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! The only thing I had to change was the length of the ranges and that solved the problem. If I replace the last semi colon by a *, I get a Value error, but leaving the semi colon, I obtain the desired value! Thanks a lot Forward Ed.

Comment: IF you are really looking for januray 2016 results per your question, then change 2015 in the formula to 2016. and your month from 12 to 1, though technically speaking you will need to update the month for each column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use arrays in excel to get this answer

```
{SUM(IF(MONTH(F$3&"1")=MONTH($A$3:$A$150),IF($E4=$B$3:$B$150,$C$3:$C$150,0),0))}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Sumproduct formula which uses array logic:

```
SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$3:$A$38)=MONTH(TEXT(G$2,"MMM")&1))*($C$3:$C$38=$F4)*
($D$3:$D$38))
```

[Sumproduct Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nagS0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Fill your month-row with the last day of each month, then apply date format to show only month name.
The formula you should use is, for example, in g8:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C;$B:$B;$E8;$A:$A;"<="&G$3;$A:$A;">"&F$3)
```

First column "F" doesn't have a column on the left to compare, so you can put a date in E3 or change a bit the formula (example of F8):

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C;$B:$B;$E8;$A:$A;"<="&F$3;$A:$A;">2015/12/31")
```

Take a look at the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx3Xr.png)

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pivot table, you can use this formula to get what you need:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$150=$E3)*(MONTH($A$3:$A$150)=1)*(YEAR($A$3:$A$150)=2015)*$C$3:$C$150)
```

Then drag-fill the cell to copy it to every month column (just make sure you change the month number in the formula (and year if you're doing that too)), and then drag-fill down the columns.

That should work pretty <strike>food</strike> good :)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help!